# How to write a new/own event for jq grid?

Tags: jqgrid

How can I write my on event in jqgrid. For example on radio button/check box change event or option change from drop down.
Like jqgrid predefined events.

Comment: The text of your question don't describe what you do. You wrote about some "radio button", "check box" and "drop down" without to clear what you mean. Do you use inline editing, form editing, searching toolbar, searching dialog, custom formatter etc.? One can't answer on your question without to understand what you do. Moreover you posted already many other question which you didn't commented or accepted. If you want to see answers on your questions in the future you should accept or at least comment your previous questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement my own "onCellClick" event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656003/how-to-implement-my-own-oncellclick-event-handler)