# How to implement my own "onCellClick" event handler

Tags: jqgrid

In my JQGrid I have check box column and drop Down drop down is created via edittype: 'select' and check boxes are created via "custom formatter" like this edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: returnCheckBox, I want to write my own "onChange" event.

So for I been able to write my "onchange" event for check box and it works fine but when I click some where else (not on check box) in check box cell and click back on check box it stop firing the "onchange" event. I think row select it causing problem how to stop it.

Here is what i am doing

```
$("#theGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            sortname: 'value1',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            cellEdit: true,
            colNames: ['SName', 'SType', 'DName', 'DType', 'Nullable'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'SName', index: 'SName', width: 100 },
                { name: 'SType', index: 'Type', width: 100 },
                {
                    name: 'DName',
                    index: 'DName',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: { value: "1:ID;2:Name" },
                },
                {
                    name: 'DType',
                    index: 'DType',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: { value: "1:BigInt;2:VarChar(50)" }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Nullable',
                    index: 'Nullable',
                    width: 100,
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'checkbox',
                    //formatter: "checkbox",
                    formatter: checkedStateChange,
                    sortable: false,
                    formatoptions: {disabled : false},
                }
            ]
        });

        var gridData = [
            { SName: 'ID', SType: 'BigInt', DName: 'ID', DType: 'BigInt' },
            { SName: 'Name', SType: 'VarChar(50)', DName: 'Name', DType: 'VarChar(50)' },

        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
            $("#theGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', gridData[i].value0, gridData[i]);
        }
     function checkedStateChange(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" class="gridCheckBox"/>';
        }
$('.gridCheckBox').on('change',function(){
alert('I am in checkBoxChange method');
});
```

Comment: @Oleg I have edited my question and added my code. Hopefully now you could guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you posted have really many small problems.

The problem with `change` exists because of at least two reasons. The first one: you have to place binding to `change` event inside of `loadComplete` callback of jqGrid. The current code bind `change` event only to **existing** checkboxs on the page. By sorting the grid for example the grid content will be rebuild and new checkboxs  will be created. So all old binding will not work more. The next problem is modifying of checkboxs *because of cell editing*. If you click in the cell with the checkbox the old content will be destroyed and *another checkbox* will be created on the same place. The checkbox will have *no* `change` binding. After the user clicks on another cell the current cell will be saved. So the editing checkbox will be destroyed and new checkbox will be created in the same place with respect of `formatter: "checkbox"` or `formatter: checkedStateChange`. As the result the `change` event handler will be exist on the checkbox.

I personally don't see any reason why you use `formatter: checkedStateChange` (or `formatter: "checkbox"` with `formatoptions: {disabled : false}`) **together** with cell editing. It makes only problems. Much more consequent would be to use `formatter: "checkbox"` *without* `formatoptions: {disabled : false}` and just to use [afterSaveCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events) callback of cell editing instead of "onchange" event.

Additional problems in your code:

- The usage of `name: 'SType', index: 'Type'` is wrong because `index` value have to be the same as `name` value in case of usage `datatype: "local"`. The current settings will don't make correct sorting or searching in the column `SType`. I strictly recommend you *to remove all `index` properties* from `colModel`
- You use `editoptions: { value: "1:BigInt;2:VarChar(50)" }` in the `DType` column which seend be wrong. Correct value should be `editoptions: { value: "BigInt:BigInt;VarChar(50):VarChar(50)" }`. If you need to use `value: "1:BigInt;2:VarChar(50)"` then the input data should contains `1` and `2` values in `DType` column and you should use [formatter: "select"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#formatter_type_select) additionally.
- You can remove `colNames` option because it contains the same value like the values of `name` property of `colModel`.
- You should *never* fill grid with data using `addRowData` called in the loop. Instead of that you should just move definition of `gridData` before creating of jqGrid and include `data: gridData` option in the grid.
- The grid have no pager. Nevertheless the local paging still work and the pager site is 20 (it's default value of the option [rowNum](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). Using `addRowData` you can fill more es 20 rows, but if the user click on a column header before starting of cell editing then the grid will be sorted and only the first 20 rows of result will be displayed. If you want to use local paging you have to include `rowNum` option with some large enough value, like `rowNum: 10000`.
- It is strictly recommended to use `gridview: true` option to improve performance of grids and to use `autoencode: true` option to interpret the input data as pure data and not like HTML fragments. It will protect you from strange errors.
- If `colModel` which you posted is full then the option `sortname: 'value1'` is wrong because the input data don't contains `value1` property.

Comment: so full and deep answer that i find some listed troubles in my grids

Comment: @Oleg I have an other question for you, _gridData_ objects has four _properties_ for first four columns, what should I place for the last column keep in mind last column is _checkBox_ column.

Comment: @Oleg I also find a way by setting _cell editing_ **false** and using _Custom Formatter_. Is it right approach??

Comment: @ozil: To provide data for `formatter: "checkbox"` you can use `true`, `false` or `1`, `0`. If you want to use custom formatter then you should test `cellvalue` parameter and generate checked checkbox (with attribute `checked="checked"`).

Comment: @Oleg By setting _cell editing_ **True** & registering my event in _loadComplete_, It is not firing the event.
`loadComplete: function () {
                registerEvents(checkBoxChange);
            },
function registerEvents(checkBoxChange) {

        $('#1_Nullable').on('change', function () {
            checkBoxChange();
        });
        
    }
{
 name: 'Nullable',
 index: 'Nullable',
 width: 100,
 
 editable: true,
 edittype: 'checkbox',
 
 }
function checkBoxChange() {
        alert('I am in checkBoxChange');
    }
`

Comment: @ozil: Sorry, but I don't full understand what you want. My suggestion was to use standard `formatter: "checkbox"` **without** `formatoptions: {disabled : false}` and `cellEdit: true`, no `loadComplete` and to add `afterSaveCell` callback **instead of** usage `on('change', ...`.

Comment: @Oleg yes by doing so it works, but the problem is I want check box always visible that's why I am using _Custom Formatter_. By using standard _Formatter_ they will only visible when I click the cell. My other column contain Drop Down, they should also be always visible.

Comment: @ozil: I don't recommend you to make checkbox visible. Instead of that you can try to use `formater: "checkboxFontAwesome4"`. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/315935) and [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FontAwesome4_Bootstrap3_2___.htm). You need just include `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css`, `jQuery.jqGrid.checkboxFontAwesome4.js` and to replace `formatter: "checkbox"` to `formatter: "checkboxFontAwesome4"`. The checkboxes will looks **not disabled**, but it will be not `<input>` controls.

Comment: @Oleg Its nice, But what about _Drop Down_ & _Radio Button_ ?

Comment: @ozil: I see no problem with the usage of `edittype: 'select'`. I personally don't see any advantage of radio buttons, but you can use it to in case of usage [edittype: 'custom'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom). See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15694509/315935) for more details.